# Validate on multiple errors with one CustomValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, business-objects, customvalidator

I am trying to figure out how to use Validation on Business Objects.

Until now I have only seen examples on *CustomValidator* that checks for only 1 error. I have two fields with DateTime input that should check for 3 or more errors. I guess normally I should check on client, then on server, last on database level.

- If I get an error on a field, I should not be able to leave the field.
- On the Client Validation this is not an error that should cause an Exception since it's only a user error. But if something goes wrong and the user bypass the Client Validation, the Server Validation should kick an Exception.
- And last, if i have other e.g. Batch Update work then they should use the Database Validation code. Please correct me if I have missed something fundamental!

1. `dateFrom` is not empty. (But `dateTo`can be empty)
2. `dateFrom` is earlier than `dateTo`
3. `dateFrom` and `dateTo` is within constant `MinDate` and `MaxDate`

So How should my Validation look like, Client, Server and Database?

*Thoughts*:

Should the validation logic be separated on 3 different places; UI, Code and DataObject(Database)? When it is the exact same code? Seems redundant?

Can I use the same validation method for all three checks? Or do I need to implement 3  code-chunks, and 3 Methods for each, and then how do I list all in the ValidationSummary nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce code duplication and the errors resulting from it, all validation code should be in a single layer - preferably the business layer, as it is in the best position to evaluate the object and determine if it is valid or not.

However, while that is a theoretical ideal, it is often not pragmatic in real world situations.  In a client-server environment, like ASP.NET, you want to duplicate as much of the validation as possible on the client side, in order to reduce round trips to the server.  Also, if you have other business procedures (such as batch uploads) that touch your table without going through your business object, you will need to implement the validation in the database as well, to prevent garbage data from being created.

For validation like in your example, I would create three validation methods on my business object and three CustomValidators - each validator would call the corresponding method on the business object on the server side.  I would also code up some JavaScript to run on the client side, so the server side code would just exist to catch non-JavaScript enabled browsers, or maliciously crafted HTTP requests.

For validation that is difficult to do in JavaScript (i.e. requires the business object), I will not bother with a CustomValidator.  Instead, those validations wait until the user presses the submit button, at which point I can use the business object to validate itself and return any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, typically, validation in the business layer is good; JS validation is also good because it helps reduce round trips.  For CustomValidator, there is a cleintvalidationfunction property that takes the name of a method to validate on the client, set it to the name of a method to do the validation (check the MSDN documentation for this, sorry, don't have the link handy, but MSDN has a clear example).

Also, for the server, the servervalidate event can also fire to validate the form from code, and you can do the DB checks here too.

Not sure what checks you do in the DataObject(Database)?

Comment: Still this way I am only validating one error, and list the one error in the Validation Summary. How can I make it validate 3 or more errors and list all of them in the ValidationSummary, without using 3 or more <asp:CustomValidator /> for each Validation i want to check?

The checks right now on DataObject(Database) is non existing but should check the same things in Client and Server Validation + DB specific specifications.

Comment: ServerValidate gives you full control over what gets validated; you can tweak the message by trying to change the erorrmessage property, or find the validator in the Page.Validators collection (you may even be able to inject validators into this collection to signal an error, I used to do this by creating a validator that always returned an error and Implemented the IValidator interface).  So there are options for using one customvalidator; you just have to write code to handle all the conditions and output the right message.